# VBA: excel data to html table entry

Tags: vba, excel, html-table

I am working on a bit of VBA code with the intention to take information from my worksheet in excel and enter into tables within web page.
Thus far I have managed to get Internet Explorer to open, my worksheet to be referenced. The code for the table I am trying to insert data to looks like:

```
    <td valign="top" align="right" class="label">
        Problem <br>Description
        <font color="red" size="+1">*</font>
    </td>
    <td class="data" colspan="5">
        <textarea name="eventVO.problemComments" cols="150" rows="3" id="eventVO.problemComments" class="data" title="Problem <br>Description">fffff</textarea>
    </td>

</tr>
```

I receive an invalid argument when I try to modify "textarea" using this code:

```
Sub FillInternetForm()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wb = Workbooks("aqe.xlsm")
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("sheet1")
'open xlm for reference

Dim IE As Object
Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium
'create new instance of IE
'With IE
IE.Navigate "url"
'go to all quality events
IE.Visible = True

'Dim Document As HTMLDocument
'Set Document = .Document
Set elems = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("tr")
'For Each e In elems

lookFor = "<td>"

For x = 2 To 10

If elems.innerText Like "eventVO.problemComments" Then
'finding correct <tr>

    elems.getElementsByTagName("textarea").Value = ws.Cells("x, 9")
    'enter problem description
    'For x = 2 To 10

    'get full html inside the <tr><tr>
    'fullHTML = e.innerHTML

End If
```

I get a runtime error 438 after if elems.getElementsByTagName. How do I get past this error and set the value for the problem description textarea as a cell value?

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns a collection of elements (even when only one matches), so you need to use something like `getElementsByTagName("textarea")(0)` to address one of the returned elements (here it's the first one)

Answer (score 0):

You have an id so use that. In theory it should be unique.

```
IE.Document.getElementById("eventVO.problemComments")
```

---

**Other:**

More HTML and/or an URL would help advise further.

However, if instead you are intending on looping over a collection of elements with `textarea` tag, then as per @TimWilliams comment, you would loop over the collection and access individual items by index. You would need to fix your assignment syntax however,  `ws.Cells("x, 9")` will not work, and I would probably use a CSS selector to get a `nodeList` to traverse.

---

**CSS selector:**

```
.document.querySelectorAll("textarea[name='eventVO.problemComments']")
```

This says select elements with tag name `textarea` that have an attribute `name` with value of `'eventVO.problemComments'`.

To the loop the returned `nodeList` you would have something like:

```
Dim x As Long, aNodeList As Object
Set aNodeList =IE.document.querySelectorAll("textarea[name='eventVO.problemComments']")

For x = 0 To aNodeList.Length -1

    aNodeList.Item(x) = ws.Cells(x+2,9)  '<Note how there is no "" inside the ()
   ' aNodeList(x) '<==potentially variation in syntax
Next x
```

---

You might also just be able to loop the collection of textarea class objects testing the name:

```
Dim a As Object, b As Object
Set a = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("textarea") '<=collection

For Each b In a
    'On Error Resume Next ''<=This may potentially be needed if not all have a name attribute
    If InStr(1, b.getAttribute("name").innerText, "eventVO.problemComments") > 0 Then   'You might be able to just say If b.Name = eventVO.problemComments
     'Do something with the matched element
    End If
    'On Error GoTo 0
Next b
```

Comment: I get a runtime error 5 at the
     aNodeList.Item(x) = ws.Cells(x + 2, 9)
could it be since I am trying to add text or is the context incorrect?

Comment: At the? Which line?

Comment: If you use the immediate window at the point it stops and put ?aNodeList.Length   ; what do you get?

Comment: 438: object does not support property or method

Comment: Which version of IE are you running? Also, if you do ?TypeName(aNodeList)   what do you get?

Comment: another 438. I am using version 11.492.16299 of IE

Comment: If you open IE and press F12 what does it say in the emulator tab for document mode?

Comment: document mode is at the default of 10

Comment: @@Idog2055 Ready when you are. I have given another alternative we can try as well.

Comment: Hi, what time zone are you? Will try and find a convenient time. Here it is 21:26 and am just winding down for tonight.

Comment: oh my, I'm in CST and is currently 15:46